# ASP.NET 5 - NETSH commands cause DNX error (determine the process id of the DNX)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dnx

I have problem with debugging of my ASP.NET 5 application after two commands in powershell for subdomain debugging (Windows 10):

Here are my steps

- Application debugging working
- Powershell commands to enable subdomain debugging are:

  ```
  Netsh http add urlacl url=http://tenant1.localhost:60903/ user=everyone
  netsh firewall add portopening TCP 60903 IISExpressWeb enable ALL
  ```
- Check to run application
- And here is comming this error message:

  ```
  "An error occurred attempting to determine the 
  process id of the DNX process hosting your application"
  ```
- powershell:

  ```
  netsh http delete urlacl url=http://tenant3.localhost:60903/ 
  netsh firewall delete portopening protocol=all port=60903
  ```
- Application run properly...

I have this problem only on my new Desktop. On my laptop with the same system (Windows 10) is this working properly...
What can I do please?

Answer (score 1):

Are there any differences between these two configurations? Could you run dnvm list and tell which runtime is set as default? Dnx is always using the default Here is could be different version of runtime, 32bit vs 64bit or clr vs coreclr.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to inform you, that i solved this issue via using one more netsh command:

```
 netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost:60903/ user=everyone
```

(without subdomain)

This command was not necessary on my second pc(laptop) in versions beta8 and RC1. 
But now is working on new machine too...